# loop throw gridview1 rows to add contents in other gridview2

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have this code and I already try debugging, there are no other problem but only one thing I dont know is how to read through the next row from the Gridview "aT" which I got from a Sql query result

```
  For Each aR As DataRow In aT.Rows
        Dim AltRow As DataRow = AltTbl.NewRow
        AltRow.Item(0) = aR.Item("OXLINC")
        AltRow.Item(1) = aR.Item("OXPART")
        AltRow.Item(2) = FormatCurrency(aR.Item("OXLSTP"))
        AltRow.Item(3) = FormatCurrency(aR.Item("OXCOST"))
        AltRow.Item("QtyRA") = QtyR
        AltRow.Item(5) = aR.Item("OXQTYA")
        AltRow.Item(8) = r.RowIndex
        AltRow.Item(9) = MFG
        AltTbl.Rows.Add(AltRow)
    Next

    If AltTbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        GridView10.DataSource = AltTbl
        GridView10.DataBind()
        GridView10.Visible = True
        GridView7.Visible = False
    End If

    For Each gR As GridViewRow In GridView10.Rows
        Dim sR As DataRow = aT.Rows(0)  //Dont know what to do here
        Dim WhseTbl As New DataTable
        WhseTbl.Columns.Add("WhseID")
        WhseTbl.Columns.Add("Qty")
        For i = 1 To 10
            If RTrim(sR.Item("OXBR" & i)) <> "" Then
                Dim wR As DataRow = WhseTbl.NewRow
                wR.Item(0) = sR.Item("OXBR" & i)
                wR.Item(1) = sR.Item("OXAV" & i)
                WhseTbl.Rows.Add(wR)
                gR.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Yellow
            End If
        Next
        If WhseTbl.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim whseG As GridView = gR.FindControl("WhGrid")
            whseG.DataSource = WhseTbl
            whseG.DataBind()
        Else
            gR.Cells(6).Text = "Not Available"
        End If
        If sR.Item("OXQTYA") >= 1 Then
            gR.BorderColor = Drawing.Color.GreenYellow
        End If
    Next
```

It only read first Row I know its obvious but I need help. I want to know what I can replace that with

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the same `DataSource` for each of the GridView controls and then handle the `RowDataBound` event for the second GridView control to do whatever formatting (color, custom text, etc.) you need for each column, based upon business rules (i.e `QXQTYA` is greater than 1)?

You can handle the `RowDataBound` event by doing the following:

Markup:

```
<asp:gridview id="GridViewB" 
    onrowdatabound="GridViewB_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server">
</asp:gridview>
```

Code-behind:

```
Sub CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        ' Do custom logic here per column
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah Thats a good Idea I should try that.. Thanks. But I just wanna read That row one by one to add a new gridview inside a cell of parent gridview row.

Comment: I found out other way too

I just Initialize a index `Dim ind As Integer = 0` and then just add more line bore `next` 

    
            ind = ind + 1
        Next
That the only way I figured out to do but still I am sure there should be another way to do this. A better way